# Understanding when a strict partial order can be satisfied by a set of integers

Tags: reference-request, order-theory

I am playing with a problem (that's part of a much bigger problem) and trying to understand the best way to approach it and also if there are existing names for this or similar problems.

If I have a set say $\{b_0,b_1,...,b_{25}\}$ with a strict partial order (transitive reduction done):

$b_0 > b_1, b_0 > b_2, b_1 > b_3, b_2 > b_3, b_4 > b_5, b_6 > b_7, b_6 > b_8$, 
$b_7 > b_9, b_8 > b_9, b_{10} > b_{11}, b_{10} > b_{12}, b_{11} > b_{13}, b_{12} > b_{13}$, 
$b_{14} > b_{15}, b_{16} > b_{17}, b_{16} > b_{18}, b_{17} > b_{19}, b_{18} > b_{19}$, 
$b_{20} > b_{21}, b_{22} > b_{23}, b_{22} > b_{24}, b_{23} > b_{25}, b_{24} > b_{25}$

Could the following values be assigned to $b_0,...,b_{25}$ so that we continue to satisfy the partial order with $>$ taking it's usual meaning for integers:

3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,0

In this case the answer is no. The Hasse diagram of the partial order 
has 8 top points that must all take the value 3. Below them are only 
13 vertices that could take the value 2 but the assignment set 
contains 14. So one 2 would have to be below another 2 which will not 
work.

I have a computer program generating millions of these problems. 
I will use Gecode (constraint satisfaction) to find cases that 
are not possible. That will give me something to play with. 
Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Well like I said in the first line. Is this a known problem. What is it called if yes? I guess I am looking for any pointers to known results that might help me solve problems like this.

Comment: It rings a bell, and I think there's a nice name for such problems (which escapes me for the moment).  I may be confusing it with the problem of which directed graphs can be realized by partial orders.

Comment: Okay, the thing I was struggling to recall is a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).  Cool name, right?  Have a look and see if it helps your problems.

Comment: Related, at Theoretical Computer Science: [Lexicographically minimal topological sort of a labeled DAG](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/31975/lexicographically-minimal-topological-sort-of-a-labeled-dag)

Comment: hardmath, Thanks for that. Looks to be the same problem.